# jquery ajax: load content from menu links

Tags: jquery, html, load

Since you most webpages are build in HTML5 I was looking for a way to load content into my content boxes from other sources (like in past you'd take php include).

So I have a index.html, where I load content into my  from other sources.

My Menu is a list with a few links:

```
<nav class="links">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="index.html">Link1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="index.html">Link2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="index.html">Link3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="index.html">Link4</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
```

Normally I load my content in with:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#content").load("content1.html");
        });
    </script>
```

How can I load different content.html pages depending on the link? Basicly how it was with include in php? I want to load the content into a

`<div id="content"></div>`

Thanks for any help!

Comment: have you tried onClick ?

Comment: Yes, but I dont know how to connect it specifically on a specific link.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by making an `if else` conditional statement. So I put the `href` value of the clicked link in the `link variable` and then conditionally you can change the content loading. :)

```js
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".links ul li a").click(function(){

                var link=$(this).attr("href"); //This here will do the trick :)

                if(link=="index.html"){ 
                    alert("load content 1"); //$("#content").load("content1.html");
                }
                else if(link=="contact.html"){
                    alert("load content 2"); //$("#content").load("content2.html");
                }
                else if(link=="about.html"){
                    alert("load content 3"); //$("#content").load("content3.html");
                }
            })
          });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="links">
        <ul>
           <li><a href="index.html">Link1</a></li>
           <li><a href="contact.html">Link2</a></li>
           <li><a href="about.html">Link3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```